# how to get images to display on the browser using the fileReader() which returns the dataURL of the image

Tags: image, dynamic, loading, filereader

`

```
` imageInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // Set the image source when the file is loaded
                cardImage.src = e.target.result;
               }; `
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              }
           });
`
```

the code allows users to enter details including images on a form.the save button saves the data in to an object and uses it elsewhere. i keep getting a 404 (Not Found) for the image path though i select from a image folder everything else like names and filler text(random description given by user) works fine but image wont load....

`

```
       saveBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            let namesValue = personNameInput.value;
            let fillerValue = paraInput.value;
            let imageFile = imageInput.files[0]; // Get the selected file`
```

upon clicking the save button i was expecting to see the namesValue indicating the persons name,fillerValue indicating their description and as expected they were displayed but the image did not show its giving error 404